# Show current location button/icon in Mapbox map swift-iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox-ios

I'm using Mapbox maps v10.7.0, how to add user location icon as like Google maps, want to show user's current location back, after user dragged the map/zoom to see other location

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox didn't provide any build-in-buttons like google to get the current location. We need to do it manually with the help of [camera positions](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/camera-and-animation/camera/)